# does a test class need to pass?

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

I have written a test class for my apex class

The test class covers 98%.

but the test class fails.

will the coverage be considered.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your test class fails it will lead to a failed deployment or failed package upload, so your test class **MUST** pass.

Also, you should not write test classes to get coverage, but to actually test your code. Otherwise they would be called **coverage classes** and not **test classes**.

Answer (score 2):

The test class needs to **pass**! Coverage is considered but 
`failed test class = failed deployment.`